# Vue template won't work with IE 11 but works with Chrome

Tags: vue.js

I created a new project with vue cli 3 (vue create test), then i added to main.js **socket.io-client** module and hit **npm run serve**, if i go to localhost:8080 on IE 11, i get the blank page but it works on Chrome... If i remove **socket.io-client** module from main.js file, the IE display the welcome page and everything works, here is my main.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

import socket from 'socket.io-client';

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset'
    ]
}
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: What errors are showing up in the IE developer console?

Comment: SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
chunk-vendors.js (1548,1)

Answer (score 0):

you can use **vue-socket.io-extend**

```
npm install vue-socket.io-extend
npm install socket.io-client
```

and in the main.js

```
import VueSocketio from 'vue-socket.io-extend'
import 'socketio' from 'socket.io-client'
Vue.use('VueSocketio',socketio('http://xxx'))
```